# Javascript - How can I take Inputs from users and show output

Tags: javascript, output, calculator

I am absolutely noob in Javascript, HTML, etc. I have a basic question for which I couldn't find a direct answer or atleast it was out of my reach of understanding.

I have made this piece of code:

```
<script>
var a = 500000;
var b = 80;
var c = (a-250000)*0.10;
var d = (a-300000)*0.10;
var e = Math.min(c,2000);
var f = Math.min(d,2000);

if (a > 250000 && a < 500001 && b < 60) { 
    document.write(e);
} else if (a > 300000 && a < 500001 && b > 59 && b < 80) {
    document.write(f);
} else {
    document.write("No Rebate");
}
</script>
```

I want to take input values of "a" and "b" from the users, perform calculation with the below code and show output (e or f or No Rebate as the case may be) to the user if the conditions set are met.

How can I do it?

What I tried till now is this

```
<form name="calc"> 
<table border="1" width="600" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
<tr><th colspan="3"><h1>TESTING</h1></th></tr>
<tr>  <th><h3>INPUT</h3></th>
<th><h3>AGE</h3></th>
<th><h3>REBATE</h3></th></tr>
<tr></tr>
<td><input type="text" name="input1" id="input1" onchange="calculate();"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="input2" id="input2" onchange="calculate();"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="output" id="output"></td>
<table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {

var a = document.calc.input1.value;
var b = document.calc.input2.value;
var c = (a-250000)*0.10;
var d = (a-300000)*0.10;
var e = Math.min(c,2000);
var f = Math.min(d,2000);

if (a > 250000 && a < 500001 && b < 60) { 
    document.calc.output.innerHTML = e;
} else if (a > 300000 && a < 500001 && b > 59 && b < 80) {
    document.calc.output.innerHTML = f;
} else {
    document.calc.output.innerHTML = "No Rebate"
}
</script>
```

(I am sure I am not using .innerHTML correctly here)

Comment: console? node? browser? Tell us what you are using to test this script. And show us what you tried

Comment: One option is to create an HTML document with a form on it consisting of text boxes and a submit button. When the submit button is clicked, store the values from the form and execute your script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create HTML input elements to capture the user input. Your script needs to read the values and do the calculation on some event like a button click, for instance:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <p>Input value a: <input type="text" onchange="return calculate();" id="txtA" /></p>
    <p>Input value b: <input type="text" onchange="return calculate();" id="txtB" /></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script>

    function calculate(){
        var a = document.getElementById('txtA').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('txtB').value;
        var c = (a-250000)*0.10;
        var d = (a-300000)*0.10;
        var e = Math.min(c,2000);
        var f = Math.min(d,2000);

        if (a > 250000 && a < 500001 && b < 60) { 
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e;
        } else if (a > 300000 && a < 500001 && b > 59 && b < 80) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = f;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "No Rebate";
        }
        return false;
    }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use `document.write` for the output, especially not after the perfectly reasonable `document.getElementById` for input (unless OP specifically requires a text-only output). In addition, `calculate()` doesn't return anything, so `return calculate()` will just return `undefined`.

Comment: used return by habit. Doesn't matter with document.write() anyway, which I never do but OP implies this is desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I was looking for but one more simple tweak in this code I am looking for, how to make the output appear in a third input box and re-perform the calculation when the same user keeps changing the input values?